# SPListItem.RoleAssignments - not an empty SPRoleAssignmentCollection, but actually null?

Tags: sharepoint-server, permissions, role-assignment

I ran into this situation a little over a year ago and asked about it on the [SP Discord channel](https://discord.com/channels/874829774902689863/876824342045032519/963091357549879307).  Here's what I asked:

> Hey, anyone ever run into a situation where the
> `SPRoleAssignmentCollection` for an item is not merely empty, it's
> actually `null`? I have a situation where the permissions for a
> document set got jacked up, and I went in with Powershell to try and
> reset permission inheritance to the library, which didn't work, and
> then I went to add a role assignment for a specific group, and when I
> tried to `$item.RoleAssignments.Add($ra)` I get an error "You cannot
> call a method on a null-valued expression."  Which seems to indicate
> that the role assignment collection itself is just gone. Which seems
> really weird.  Not sure how to get a new role assignment collection
> added so I can rebuild the permissions.

I never was able to resolve the issue, and now it's come up again - I have another document set, in the same library, that does not have an empty `SPRoleAssignmentCollection` for `SPListItem.RoleAssignments`.

`SPListItem.RoleAssignments` is `null`.

How can I repopulate that property with an `SPRoleAssignmentCollection` so I can add some role assignments and get back into the document set?

Looking at the documentation for [`SPRoleAssignmentCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ms412299(v=office.14)), there is no constructor, so you can't just `new` up a collection.

And if I remember correctly, I tried looking up ways to use reflection to call internal/hidden methods (in this case, a contructor), but I wasn't able to get that to work.

Any ideas as to what I can do here to recover this thing?